# CSV not encoding when trying to send as attachment using php

Tags: php, email, csv, encoding

I am trying to create a csv file on the fly and email it. Unfortunately, the file is not being created but the data is being encrypted. Could someone point me in the right direction please?  This is the output I receive via email..

'

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--NextPart_001

Content-Type: text/plain; charset='us-ascii'

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

See Attached File

--NextPart_001

Content-Type: text/csv;  name='LastName FirstName.csv'

Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Content-Disposition: attachment

Rmlyc3QgTmFtZSxMYXN0IE5hbWUsRW1haWwgQWRkcmVzcyxQaG9uZSBOdW1iZXIsQWRkcmVzcyxD 
aXR5LFN0YXRlLFppcCBDb2RlLE1vbnRoLERheSxZZWFyLEV2ZW50IFR5cGUsRGVzY3JpcHRpb24s 
U3RhcnQgSG91cixTdGFydCBRdWFydGVyIEhvdXIsU3RhcnQgQU0vUE0sUGljay11cCBBZGRyZXNz 
LE90aGVyIFN0b3BzLEVuZCBIb3VyLEVuZCBRdWFydGVyIEhvdXIsRW5kIEFNL1BNLEZpbmFsIERl 
c3RpbmF0aW9uLE51bWJlciBPZiBQYXNzZW5nZXJzLFByZWZlcnJlZCBWZWhpY2xlLEhvdyBkaWQg 
eW91IGZpbmQgdXMKTWljaGFlbCxQcmF0dCxtaWtlLnByYXR0QGJlc3R0cmFuc3BvcnRhdGlvbi5j 
b20sMzE0LTIyMi01MzMyLDg1MzEgUGFnZSBBdmUgU3RlIDE2MCxTYWludCBMb3VpcyxNaXNzb3Vy 
aSw2MzExNC02MDA3LERlYywzMSwyMDEzLFNwZWNpYWwgRXZlbnQsLDk6LDAwLHBtLDEwMTAwIFBp 
bmVodXJzdCBEcg0KT3ZlcmxhbmQsIE1PIDYzMTE0LEFzIERpcmVjdGVkLCwwMCwsMTAxMDAgUGlu 
ZWh1cnN0IERyDQpPdmVybGFuZCwgTU8gNjMxMTQsMTAsRXhlY3V0aXZlIE1pbmkgQ29hY2ggMTMg 
cGF4LE90aGVyCg==

--NextPart_001--

Here is the code I am using...

```
$cr = "\n";

$csvdata = "First Name" . ',' . "Last Name" . ',' . "Email Address" . ',' . "Phone Number" . ',' . "Address" . ',' . "City" . ',' . "State" . ',' . "Zip Code" . $cr;

$csvdata .= $firstname . ',' . $lastname . ',' . $email . ',' . $phone . ',' . $address . ',' . $city . ',' . $state . ',' . $zip . $cr;

$encoded = chunk_split(base64_encode($csvdata));

$thisfile = $lastname . ' ' . $firstname . '.csv';

$to3 = "me@mydomain.com";
$subject3 = "CSV Attachment";
$headers3 = "From: Someone <someone@somedomain.com>\n" .   "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary='NextPart_001' . '\n'";


$message3 = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--NextPart_001
Content-Type: text/plain; charset='us-ascii'
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

See Attached File

--NextPart_001
Content-Type: text/csv;  name='$thisfile'
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment
$encoded
--NextPart_001--";
```

Comment: If you view the message headers, do you see the `MIME-Version` and `Content-type` headers?

Comment: Try removing the quotes in `boundary='NextPart_001'`

Comment: So it should read... "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=NextPart_001 . '\n'" ??

Comment: I removed the quotes as suggested but still receive the same results as posted above.

Comment: The quotes are optional, but if you have them they should be double quotes. I think the actual problem may be that you're separating header lines with `\n` rather than `\r\n`.

Comment: changed to \r\n... same results

Comment: Are you using Gmail to receive the file attachment email?  If so, this is a known issue in Gmail.  Unfortunately for both of us, it doesn't seem to be a FIXED known issue in Gmail...  https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/gmail/reading-and-receiving-messages/L0rwZfE1exc